# Add a new row into ListView

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I am using the following code to add a new row into a two columns ListView:

```
// First column
LVITEM lvi;
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.pszText = "Some Name";
lvi.iItem = 0;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
SendMessage(hListView, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvi);

// Second column
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.pszText = "Some Address";
lvi.iItem = 0;
lvi.iSubItem = 1;
SendMessage(hListView, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvi);
```

My question is how can I add a new row (into a ListView that is not empty), I tried to increment the value of `lvi.iItem` by `1`, so for example if I have 5 rows and I want to add a new one, I set the value of `lvi.iItem` to `5`.

This approach has worked but I am not sure if it is correct or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LVM_INSERTITEM` returns the index of the new item. Use that index when sending `LVM_SETITEM`.  Also, `LVM_INSERTITEM` inserts the new item at the specified `iItem` index, so if `iItem` is 0 then the new item is inserted at the front of the list. To insert at the end of the list instead, set `iItem` to the result of `LVM_GETITEMCOUNT`:

```
// First column
LVITEM lvi;
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.pszText = "Some Name";
lvi.iItem = SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
int index = SendMessage(hListView, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvi);
if (index != -1)
{
    // Second column
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvi.pszText = "Some Address";
    lvi.iItem = index;
    lvi.iSubItem = 1;
    SendMessage(hListView, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvi);
}
```

Comment: So when adding a new row (`LVM_INSERTITEM`), I should set `lvi.iItem` to `0`, and only giving it a different value when adding a Subitem (`LVM_SETITEM`)?

Comment: Yes. `LVM_INSERTITEM` is adding a new item, so there is no index yet, so `iItem` must be 0.  But once an item is added, subsequent messages for that item must use its current index.

Comment: I have tried to set `lvi.iItem` to `0` to add a second row, but it replaced the first row! (the first row became the second row).

Comment: My bad. As the `LVM_INSERTITEM` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107.aspx) says: "*Use the iItem member to specify the **zero-based index at which the new item should be inserted**. If this value is greater than the number of items currently contained by the listview, the new item will be appended to the end of the list and assigned the correct index.*"  Thus, if `iItem` is 0, `LVM_INSERTITEM` will insert the new item at the front of the list, not the end. To insert at the end of the list, set `iItem` to the result of `LVM_GETITEMCOUNT`.

Comment: If sort flag is on, then item could end up anywhere. The above method should always determine the new item's position. If sort flag is off, then set `iItem` to either zero for insert, or `GETITEMCOUNT` for append.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: "*The LVM_INSERTITEM message will insert the new item in the proper position in the sort order if the following conditions hold:
•You are using one of the LVS_SORTXXX styles. 
•You are not using the LVS_OWNERDRAW style. 
•The pszText member of the structure pointed to by pitem is not set to LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK.*"  That implies that `iItem` is ignored by `LVM_INSERTITEM` if sorting is enabled.